# Configure Github Workflow Action to send result of action to slack message

Tags: continuous-integration, slack-api, github-actions

I am struggling with outputting the result of action to slack message.

This is what I have tried so far

```
jobs:
  scratch-org-test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      deploy: ${{ steps.deploy.outputs:text }}
      apex-tests: ${{ steps.apex-tests.outputs.text }}
    steps:
      - name: "Push source to scratch org"
        id: "deploy"
        run: echo "::set-output name=text::$(sfdx force:source:push)"
      - name: 'Run Apex tests'
        run: 'sfdx force:apex:test:run -c -r human -d ./tests/apex -w 20'
      
      - uses: pCYSl5EDgo/cat@master
        id: hello
        with:
          path: ./tests/apex/test-result.txt

      - name: 'Output Apex Tests Execution results'
        id: "apex-tests"
        run: echo "::set-output name=text::${{ steps.hello.outputs.text }}"

  slack-notification-with-optional-parameters:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: scratch-org-test
    name: Sends a message to Slack when a push, a pull request or an issue is made
    steps:
      - name: Send message to Slack API
        uses: archive/github-actions-slack@v1.0.3
        id: notify
        with:
          slack-bot-user-oauth-access-token: {{secrets.token}}
          slack-channel: random
          slack-text: Deploy ${{needs.scratch-org-test.outputs.deploy}} Apex-tests ${{needs.scratch-org-test.outputs.apex-tests}}
          slack-optional-icon_emoji: ":fire:"
      - name: Result from "Send Message"
        run: echo "The result was ${{ steps.notify.outputs.slack-result }}"
```

What I receive

[image]

Looks like the complete output is not passed to the output variable. I don't understand why. When I look at Github Actions, I can see the whole output there but not in the slack message.

What I am trying to achieve:

NotifierAPP  10:51 AM
Deploy

```
Run echo "::set-output name=text::$(sfdx force:source:push)"
SOURCE PROGRESS | ████████████████████████████████████████ | 0/0 Components
SOURCE PROGRESS | ████████████████████████████████████████ | 0/0 Components
SOURCE PROGRESS | ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ | 0/61 Components
SOURCE PROGRESS | ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ | 0/61 Components
SOURCE PROGRESS | ███░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ | 4/61 Components
SOURCE PROGRESS | ███░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ | 4/61 Components
SOURCE PROGRESS | ████████████████████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ | 37/61 Components
SOURCE PROGRESS | ████████████████████████████░░░░░░░░░░░░ | 42/61 Components
SOURCE PROGRESS | ███████████████████████████████████████░ | 60/61 Components
SOURCE PROGRESS | ███████████████████████████████████████░ | 60/61 Components
SOURCE PROGRESS | ███████████████████████████████████████░ | 60/61 Components
SOURCE PROGRESS | ████████████████████████████████████████ | 61/61 Components
SOURCE PROGRESS | ████████████████████████████████████████ | 61/61 Components
```

=== Pushed Source
STATE  FULL NAME                                                              TYPE                      PROJECT PATH
─────  ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────  ────────────────────────  ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

```
Apex Tests

=== Apex Code Coverage
ID                  NAME                        % COVERED  UNCOVERED LINES
──────────────────  ──────────────────────────  ─────────  ───────────────
01p1j000004BegPAAS  Class1                      100%
01p1j000004BegUAAS  Class2                      100%
01p1j000004BegGAAS  Class3                      100%
01q1j000000rclOAAQ  Class4                      100%
01p1j000004BegIAAS  Class5                      100%
01p1j000004BegOAAS  Class6                      100%
01p1j000004BegTAAS  Class7                      100%
01p1j000004BegKAAS  Class8                      100%
01p1j000004BegNAAS  Class9                      100%
01p1j000004BegRAAS  Class10                     100%
```

Is there any way to send the complete output to slack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I have found [solution here](https://github.community/t/set-output-truncates-multiline-strings/16852)

Basically new lines should be escaped to make it work.

Also I don't really need `CYSl5EDgo/cat@master` action, instead I could just use the `cat` command.

```
  - name: "Push source to scratch org"
    id: "deploy"
    run: |
      deploy=$(sfdx force:source:push)
      echo $deploy  
      deploy="${deploy//'%'/'%25'}"
      deploy="${deploy//$'\n'/'%0A'}"
      deploy="${deploy//$'\r'/'%0D'}"
      echo "::set-output name=text::$deploy"

  - name: 'Run Apex tests'
    run: 'sfdx force:apex:test:run -c -r human -d ./tests/apex -w 20'

  - name: 'Output Apex Tests Execution results'
    id: "apex-tests"
    run: |
      text=$(cat ./tests/apex/test-result.txt)
      echo $text  
      text="${text//'%'/'%25'}"
      text="${text//$'\n'/'%0A'}"
      text="${text//$'\r'/'%0D'}"
      echo "::set-output name=text::$text"
```